# A way to measure execution time of a function on Cortex-m1

Tags: arm, timing, cortex-m

i'm looking for a way to measure how many clock cycles a function takes to execute on arm Cortex-M1.
There isn't much documentation on the topic, everything i've found is about using DWT and DWT is not implemented on Cortex-M1 (at least i think so, i can't find it in the technical reference manual).

Comment: systick gives the same results as DWT if not using a divided clock.  if systick is implemented. otherwise have to use a timer

Comment: also understand the pitfalls of trying to time code esp with high performance cores like arm.  alignment alone can have a major affect on execution...

Comment: cortex-m1 means you are in an fgpa right?  just add your own timer, or just run the code in sim and count clocks there using a sim clock counter

Comment: @old_timer Yeah, i'm on a arty a7. Where can i check if systick is implemented?

Comment: just try talking to it...see if its there...

Comment: @old_timer Yep, tried that, it's there :D Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the systick timer is present and if you feed it the same clock as the system clock it will give you the same results as DWT.  If it is a divided clock it will still provide useful information.   Beware that simple things like alignment of the code can have dramatic affect on the performance of the code.

If you do not have a systick timer you can try to use a timer peripheral.  Being a cortex-m1 you could add a simple counter and add it to the address space.